# Count combinations of 4 elements where order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem because I need to implement it in my program. Let's say we have given 4 numbers $A, B, C, D$. Now we want to count all possible pairs of $(i, j, k, l)$ 
where

$1\leq i \leq A\\1\leq j \leq B\\1\leq k \leq C\\1\leq l \leq D$

Please note that order doesn't matter, so $(1, 1, 2, 1) = (1, 2, 1, 1) = (2, 1, 1 ,1)\dots$ and the numbers $(A, B, C, D)$ can be up to $3000$.

**What I tried**

This is how I think that the problem can be solved.

Because there are more overlapping situations, for the first number, $i$ the numbers that can be placed on that position are in range $[1, A]$. Then for the second number, $j$ the numbers should be in range $[A, B]$, for $k$ the numbers can be in range $[B, C]$ and for $l$ the range is $[C, D]$. I think that this should be done because the order doesn't matter, but I don't know how to turn this into numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\multiset}[2]{\left(\!\binom{#1}{#2}\!\right)} \newcommand{\tmultiset}[2]{\big(\!\binom{#1}{#2}\!\big)}$
WLOG you can assume $A\ge B\ge C\ge D$. It then suffices to count tuples $(i,j,k,l)$ where $i\ge j\ge k \ge l$, and where $i\le A, j\le B,k\le C,l\le D$, since the decreasing arrangement of any legal tuple is legal.

Let $f$ be a function so that $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [1,D]$, $f(x)=2$ for $x\in (D,C]$, $f(x)=3$ for $x\in (C,B]$, and $f(x)=4$ for $x\in (B,A]$, and define the signature of a tuple $(i,j,k,l)$ to be $(f(i),f(j),f(k),f(l))$. There are only $14$ possible signatures. Furthermore, it is easy to count the number of tuples with a given signature. For example, the number of tuples...

- with signature $(3,3,1,1)$ is $\tmultiset{B-C}2\times \tmultiset{D}2$
- with  signature $(4,2,2,1)$ is $\tmultiset{A-B}1\times\tmultiset{C-D}2\times \tmultiset{D}1$
- with signature $(1,1,1,1)$ is $\tmultiset{D}4$.

Recall that $\multiset{n}k=\binom{n+k-1}k$ is the number of multisets of size $k$ taken from a set of $n$ elements. So, just find all possible signatures, do that formula for each one, then add them all up.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the abstract thinking, and I sort of get it I think. What about a condensed bruteforce way? For 5,4,3,1, for example, it'd be 1111, 2111, 3111, 4111, 5111, 2211, 3211...so on. It'd be something like 5+4+3+2+4+3+2+3+2. It's like that but expressed using abcd.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following pseudocode will work . . .

Relabel $A,B,C,D\;$so that $A \le B \le C \le D$.

```
   function f(A,B,C,D)
      x = 0
      for i from 1 to A do
         for j from i to B do
            for k from j to C do
               for l from k to D do
                  x = x + 1            
               end do
            end do
         end do
      end do
      return x
   end

   Example run . . .

   input:   f(4,7,10,12)

   output:  829
```

For larger numbers, a recursion (with memoization), is much more efficient.

Here's an implementation in Maple . . .

[image]

Notes:

- The input to $f$ is expected to be a finite, nonempty, non-decreasing list of positive integers.

  If implemented in C, it would be about $200$ times faster (so essentially instant).

Comment: This code works fine, but it gets slower when numbers are becoming larger, because it's complexity is $O(N^4)$

Comment: My latest edit includes a recursive version which is much faster.